# line-height:0 puts the image in vertical center of button

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I saw this code in other site, when I tried to center the `img` in a `button` vertically.

```css
button {
  line-height: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
img {
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <img 
       src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/action/search_24px.svg" 
       alt="search" />
</button>
```

Without `line-height: 0;` image is not exaclty verticaly center of the button. But when we put `line-height: 0;` it's gone perfect. I tested it in chrome 50. Why is this happening?

http://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/ezmYwm

Comment: If you will set the image `display:block` and remove the `line-height` it will works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `line-height: normal` didn't worked because the value of "normal" is not just a single concrete value that is applied to all elements, but rather computes to a "reasonable" value depending on the font size set (or inherited) on the element. `Height` and `line-height` are two different things. That's why you didn't get vertically `centered` output.

And `line-height: 0` set the height of the line of text as null. Clearing the default `line-height` of the text.

You can vertically align the element using `vertical-align: middle` rule

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
}
img {
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button>
   <img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/action/search_24px.svg" alt="search" />
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, So I think default line-height is adding some pixels to the button even if there is no text, right? When we reset it to 0, image will align vertically, I suppose.